# Cannot run Espresso test while showing MapView

Tags: android, android-espresso

When there is an active MapView on display and the there is a Espresso click action to perform the app stays idle for like 30 seconds and throws an exeption:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not launch intent Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x14000000 cmp=com.example.dun.mapviewtest/.MainActivity } within 45 seconds. Perhaps the main thread has not gone idle within a reasonable amount of time? There could be an animation or something constantly repainting the screen. Or the activity is doing network calls on creation? See the threaddump logs. For your reference the last time the event queue was idle before your activity launch request was 1489270614900 and now the last time the queue went idle was: 1489270614900. If these numbers are the same your activity might be hogging the event queue.
        at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.startActivitySync(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:360)
        at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.launchActivity(ActivityTestRule.java:219)
        at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:268)
        at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
        at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
        at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1944)
```

why is this happening and how do y resolve it?

I know the ui thread have to be idle for the action to perform but then, how do i test an app with a mapView?